# reinitialize arraylists between activities error

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity

I have two activities `LoginActivity` and `MyMapActivity`. The problem is when I try to open the `MyMapActivity` (Login->MyMapActivity (first time activity works)-> Logout -> Login) for second time I get the following error:

```
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pac/com.example.pac.MyMapActivity}:    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at com.example.pac.MyMapActivity.onCreate(MyMapActivity.java:232)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-10 06:55:27.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3630):     ... 11 more
```

Line 232 in MyMapActivity:

```
fantasma1 = myMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(rlevel.get(v)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable .marker_white)));
```

MyMapActivity class:

```
public class MyMapActivity extends Activity implements AnimationLayout.Listener {
public final static String TAG = "Demo";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

        setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);
        deigma = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mLayout = (AnimationLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
        mLayout.setListener(this);
        /*permissions gia parse twn sintetagmenwn*/

    //telos permission
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
    //logout
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
           Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(login);





            // Closing dashboard screen
           finish();
        }
    });
    //telos logout


    /*menu
     */


    //telos

    /* user location settings */
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = null;
      //  locationManager.getlastfix().reset();
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)||locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(true);

        //API level 9 and up
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
        criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        deigma.setText(String.valueOf(locationManager));
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
        /*if (location != null) {
            Log.e("PROVIDER SCELTO", provider);
            onLocationChanged(location);
            Log.e("LATITUDE", String.valueOf("da"));
            Log.e("LONGITUDE", String.valueOf("no"));
        }*/
        }
    //telos rithmisewn






/* Helper function. put it in the same page, or in a library */
protected static String downloadFile(String url) {

// to fill-in url content
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// local objects declarations
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

try {
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) {
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
builder.append(line);
}
} else {
// Failed to download file

}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return builder.toString();
}



/*telos*/
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
{ 

@Override 
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    float accuracy = (float) location.getAccuracy();
    //deigma.setText(Float.toString(accuracy));
//updateWithNewLocation(location); 
    myLocationMarker.remove();
    lat =  location.getLatitude();
     lng = location.getLongitude();
    thesi_xristi=new LatLng(lat,lng);
   myLocationMarker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(thesi_xristi)
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.k)));

   for(int vb23=0;vb23<markers_balls.size();vb23++){
       double rla = rballs.get(vb23).latitude;
       double rlo = rballs.get(vb23).longitude;
       if(calculateDistance(lat, lng, rla, rlo,"M")<0.00080){
           markers_balls.get(vb23).remove();
           markers_balls.remove(vb23);  
           score=score+10;
       }
   }

   deigma.setText(score +" ac: "+accuracy);
} 

@Override 
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 
//updateWithNewLocation(null); 

}


@Override 
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 
} 

@Override 
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 
} 

}; 



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
        String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                getApplicationContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyMapActivity.this);
        LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
        LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
        LicenseDialog.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            //  "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}
private double calculateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) 
{
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      if (unit == "K") {
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
      } else if (unit == "M") {
        dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
      return (dist);
}

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private double deg2rad(double deg) 
    {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private double rad2deg(double rad)
    {
      return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }



    public void onClickContentButton(View v) {
        mLayout.toggleSidebar();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mLayout.isOpening()) {
            mLayout.closeSidebar();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    /* Callback of AnimationLayout.Listener to monitor status of Sidebar */
    @Override
    public void onSidebarOpened() {
        Log.d(TAG, "opened");
    }

    /* Callback of AnimationLayout.Listener to monitor status of Sidebar */
    @Override
    public void onSidebarClosed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "opened");
    }

    /* Callback of AnimationLayout.Listener to monitor status of Sidebar */
    @Override
    public boolean onContentTouchedWhenOpening() {
        // the content area is touched when sidebar opening, close sidebar
        Log.d(TAG, "going to close sidebar");
        mLayout.closeSidebar();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         super.onPause();
          rlevel.clear();
          rlevel2.clear();
          rlevel3.clear();
          rballs.clear();
          markers_balls.clear();

          go.cancel();

        }

}
```

I am trying to reinitialize the arraylists `onDestroy`, but, I am getting the same problem.

Comment: I recommend you to extract only the code around com.example.pac.MyMapActivity.onCreate(MyMapActivity.java:232) and also the related function, but not pasting the whole class here which creates troubles for others to read.

Comment: the problem is that most functions contains arraylists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occur Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

The arraylist is  re initialize but not added any value on arraylist. so the arraylist size is zero.

You fetch the value at the index of 0.

So its throws indeoutofboundsexception.

Please check the arraylist size before fetch the value.

Comment: could you give me more details.Sorry but i'm begginer

Comment: you are trying get value in rlevel,rlevel2,rlevel3  arraylist at the index of zero . rlevel.get(v)

Comment: before get the value check the rlevel,rlevel2,rlevel3 arraylist size.

Comment: arrays get values from json parser... i' going to try this if(rlevel.size()>0){
   fantasma1 = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(rlevel.get(v)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_white)));
   } but the problem exists

Comment: rlevel get lat & lng (directions) from server via json parser.every time this Activity starts parse directions from url

Comment: check the rlevel2 and rlevel3

Comment: in your code at the line number 251, which arraylist is there.  the problem occurs at the line number 251

Comment: i check arraylists size at the line number 251 and now activity works but rlevel,rlevel2 and rlevel3 are empty!json parser get values only in rballs array

Comment: the problem must be occurs in function public static void Decode(String result) at the line 311

Comment: i'm trying every time where MyMapActivity starts to parse new values from server

Comment: ok!!the problem solved! i reset the metr_routes variable (counter) onDestroy()